# Regex to extract String between two expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a log file that contains sent and received messages. I want to extract these message using a regular expression. This is an example of log file:

```
Message recieved:0908082349234 Session: ...
A message is sent: 12344384834
```

I wrote the following regex to extract the message:

```
String pattern = "((A message is sent: )|(Message received:))(.*)(( Session:)|$)";
```

And it doesn't work. I tried many different forms of it but none of them worked. I want to do this using a single regex. Right now I use one regex for sent and another one for received. But there should be a way to use a single regex for both of them!

Comment: what does not work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` matches greedily. Use non-greedy version (`.*?`):

```
String pattern = "(A message is sent: |Message received:)(.*?)( Session:|$)";
```

BTW, the given log file contains a typo. If the log file really contains the typo, you should adjust the regular expression accordingly.

```
Message recieved:0908082349234 Session: ...
           ^^
```

Comment: This doesn't match the first one.

Comment: @hwnd, IMHO, removing space does not make different because the log file contains space before `Session`.

Comment: I was just letting you know =)

Comment: Thanks! This one worked. Just a comment! I used matcher.group() and the result contained "A message is sent:" at beginning and "Session:" at the end. Then I changed it to matcher.group(2) and I got my result!

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
"((A message is sent: )|(Message recieved:))(\\d+?)(.*)"
```

btw. it seems that you 'recieved' is miss matching between your log and your pattern

Comment: That was a typing mistake!